# XML protected characters

Tags: xml, special-characters

Which are the XML protected characters and what is their equivalent substitute, HTML, `\` notation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be satisfied by reading the [List of XML and HTML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references) on Wikipedia, with particular emphasis on
[Predefined entities in XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Predefined_entities_in_XML)
and
[Character entity references in HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references#Character_entity_references_in_HTML).

Answer (score 1):

Does this help:
http://xml.silmaril.ie/specials.html

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia: [List of XML and HTML character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references)